# Android Alarm Manager Plus with Flutter: How to get Id of active Alarm?

Tags: flutter, alarmmanager

I'm quite new to Flutter and trying to implement a simple Alarm App with the Android *Alarm Manager Plus package*. Below is the example code from the documentation that looks similar. My App successfully schedules and fires multiple alarms, however I can't find a good way to cancel a firing alarm.

```
static void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

main() async {
  // Be sure to add this line if initialize() call happens before runApp()
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}
```

I would like to write a function similar to this:

```
cancel = await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(id);
```

But how do I get the ID? I saved all scheduled Alarms and their IDs to a list. Should I simply assume that, if I sort the list by time, the next one on my list is the active alarm, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

now this time there is no solution for alarms in the background. I also find the solution but I can't find it, there are many limitations in a flutter. I used many flutter plugins but did not achieve the alarms.

if anyone finds the solution the answer is this.

I also try this package **alarm: ^0.0.6** but did not achieve it.